# Is there any way to initialize variables from object and class names?(such as by using reflections)

Tags: java, oop, reflection

For example:
let us say there is a class Dog , a subclass Dalmatian and the Dog class has private variables
String name, breed;
Now I say in main:

```
Dog spot = new Dalamatian();
```

and automatically it get name = "spot" and breed = "Dalmatian".

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to get the breed:

```
public class Dog {
    private final String name;
    private final String breed;

    protected Dog(String name) {
        // Default to using the class name
        this(name, getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    protected Dog(String name, String breed) {
        // Allow subclasses to specify an explicit breed
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
    }
}
```

I don't believe there's any way of inferring `spot` though in Java. (You can do it in C#, assuming this is a field rather than a local variable, using `CallerMemberName`...)

So basically you'd need

```
Dog spot = new Dalmation("spot");
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually wanted to write public or protected, but ended up writing private - but in the end I decided not to edit it. It would be nice though if I could get the "spot" as well.